# Catch DataRowChanged Event in Dictionary<int, List<DataSet>>

Tags: c#, winforms, events, dictionary, datarow

How can I catch `DataRowChanged` event for each `DataTable` in `Dictionary<int, List<DataSet>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
foreach(var kvp in dictionary){
kvp.Value.ForEach(dataset=>dataset.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().ToList().ForEach(table=>table.RowChanged+=yourhandler));
}
```

Or longer version:

```
foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
{
    foreach(var dataset in kvp.Value)
    {
        foreach(var table in dataset.Tables)
        {  
            table.RowChanged+=yourhandler;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat difficult to read, plus I'm not fond of the nested usage of `foreach` and `ForEach<T>`.

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference. For me it's simple construct.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Dictionary<int, List<DataSet>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<DataSet>>();
    foreach (var d in dict)
    {
        foreach (DataSet ds in d.Value)
        {
            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                dt.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(dt_RowChanged);    
            }
        }
    }
```